# Error while specifying servlet mapping in RAD

Tags: servlets, web.xml, ibm-rad, servlet-mapping

I want to add a new servlet mapping in my java web project in IBM RAD 8.5.1

There are already two existing servlets in my application:
ServletOne and ServletTwo

but when I do new > servlet mapping, It gives the following error in the wizard:

```
This wizard is not applicable for projects without web.xml file.
```

The web.xml is already present in the project and has following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>MyApplication</display-name>
        <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletOne</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.myclass.ClassOne</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletTwo</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.myclass.ClassTwo</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>  
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

location of web.xml is:
    /WebContent/WEB-INF/

I tried adding the servlet mapping directly in web.xml source xml file but then it gives following error in servlet name:

```
The value is not among the possible selectors
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Is this an unmodified copy paste of web.xml? You've there some illegal whitespace in tag names which will obviously cause trouble.

Comment: oh yes, the spaces came when I copied it here. I correct it.